# Mapping collection based on how many times item been called

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, dictionary, lodash

Below I have an `arrary` (`arr`) containing `objects` with two properties `id` and `content`, I need to map over this `array` and return and `array` where the item with the same `id` are `shift`ed from the array in order from left to right.

```
var arr = [
  {
    'id': '32423423',
    'content': ['one']
  },
  {
    'id': '23456789',
    'content': ['one', 'two', 'three']
  },
  {
    'id': '23456789',
    'content': ['one', 'two', 'three']
  },
  {
    'id': '23456789',
    'content': ['one', 'two', 'three']
  }
  {
    'id': '13123123',
    'content': ['two']
  }
]
```

The desired output would be this:

```
var output = [
  'one',
  'one',
  'two',
  'three'.
  'two'
]
```

An array of the `content` items.

Comment: So, basically, you need to remove duplicates and then create an array that contains only the remaining items in each `content` property?

Comment: No I need duplicates @taylorc93 check my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use [reduce()](https://lodash.com/docs#reduce) for this.

```
_.reduce(arr, function(result, item) {
    this.push(item.id);
    return result.concat(item.content[_.countBy(this)[item.id] - 1]);
}, [], []);
```

You'll notice that there's two arrays passed into `reduce()`, after the iteratee function. The first array is the accumulator, used to build our result. The second array is the function context - this is a little trick used to avoid creating a global variable outside of the function. And we need one for keeping track of IDs.

The first thing we do in the callback function is add the `item.id` to the list of seen IDs (`this`). Then we concat the appropriate `content` to the result, and move onto the next item.

The reason we're keeping track of the IDs is so that we can count the number of each unique ID using [countBy()](https://lodash.com/docs#countBy). This is how we figure out the index position of `content`, based on the number of duplicate IDs.

Answer (score 0):

```
var _ = require('lodash')

function mapShiftOver (data, item) {
  var master = _.chain(data).indexBy(item).values().value()
  return _.map(data, function (item) {
    var masterItem = _.find(master, {
      'item': item.id
    })
    if (!masterItem) return undefined
    return masterItem.content.shift()
  })
}
```